# Is it necessary to use the word officially at end of the expression?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-in-context

A new manager was employed in our school, some of the staff occasionally met with him for some reason but not officially. And the new manager did not call for an official meeting. So the staff thought it wise to officially meet him for an introduction.

In his office, one of the staff began in the meeting by saying **"Sir, as you can see, these are St. Garvan's nursery and primary school staff, we have discovered that since your appointment with the school we haven't met...."**

After the meeting, one of the staff said I should have said [...since your appointment with the school we haven't met officially]. That I should have included officially.

Is it necessary to include the word **officially** at the end of the expression?

Comment: If it's an official meeting, then, yes, 'officially' would not be out of place in the place you ask about. Do you really have to call the manager 'Sir'?

Comment: Michael Harvey, is there a title I should use apart from that?

Comment: I'm not very clear what "officially" means in this context.  I think you mean a "meeting as required by policy and which has a certain preset structure".  But then why would you say "we have discovered ...".  St Garvan sounds like Ireland? is it?

Comment: Okay. Thank you, James K

Comment: In British culture, you would use the person's name, as you are all colleagues in a school (and so peers) you would probably use first name.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "officially" makes sense, if it is meaningful to you.  It is grammatically optional, so there is no language reason to say "officially".  But if you want to clarify that "We have met you unofficially but we haven't met you officially", then you need to add the word.  The meaning of "officially" isn't implied if you don't say it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some administrative/bureaucratic convention or policy, officially seems questionable to me. The use of 'official' for any purpose would imply a formally required or sanctioned activity or product.

In this case, I do not think you are required to use 'officially' or 'appointment to the school board' (vs. 'appointment'). The former because there likely wasn't an official aspect of the introductions (we lack that context to be sure) and the latter because 'the appointment' would be understood by all present to be 'to the school board' and thus the shorthand would be sufficient.

I might have said:

"Sir, it has come to our attention that you have may not have been formally introduced to all of the staff of St. Gavin's nursary and primary school. We felt such an introduction would be beneficial for all, if this is a good time."

But I think what the poster said was grammatically fine.

Comment: "Might have went with" is bad English.

Comment: It's a common usage in the business world in my experience. It could be improved and thus I will make a change to the answer. Frequently I've heard phrases like "I (or we) went with .that (or something specific like 'the foursquare proposal')" or "You should have went with <something>".

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that in Standard English, they can say 'I (or we) went with...' but 'you should have **gone** with _something_'

Comment: I see what you were getting at and agree. Your example seems to be a good one.